# No module named Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu-14.04

Even after successfully installing selenium-2.48.0
I am getting an error on importing the selenium package

```
    >>> from Selenium import webdriver
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named selenium
```

and when I try to install selenium again using pip install selenium it shows the error:

```
    Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Comment: Are you using python3? The package is installed for python3 and you should get this error if you try to import in python2

Comment: use python3 command on ubuntu to execute your files.

Comment: alecxe is right the name should be lower case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using python 2 instead of python 3
Thanks [@Kamejoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899745/kamejoin) to figure it out in comments

Answer (score 5):

Sure, there is no module named `Selenium`.

But, hopefully, there is one named `selenium`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo mistake by me in the question 
the terminal displays : 
        no module named selenium

Comment: I was wrong at the fact that I was using python 2 instead of python 3

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing. I'll leave the answer as is, in case someone has this problem.

Comment: Made the same mistake haha. Thank you for this! Would've taken me ages to catch